# authenticate a user and create token with credentials in different tables

Tags: php, laravel, api, authentication, jwt

how can i authenticate user and create jwt token for that with username field in users table and password fields in another table ?

```
 $credentials = [
        'phone' => $request->phone,
        'confirm.password' => $request->confirmation_code,
    ];
    try {
        // attempt to verify the credentials and create a token for the user
        if (! $token = JWTAuth::attempt($credentials)) {
            return response()->json(['state' => False, 'error' => 'Invalid Credentials.'], 401);
        }
    } catch (JWTException $e) {
        // something went wrong whilst attempting to encode the token
        return response()->json(['state' => False, 'error' => 'can not create token !'], 500);
    }
```

my password is in confirm table and password field. the user table in related to confirm table in thier model.